# Comparing datetime object to Panda series elements

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to compare a datetime object to a date stored in a Panda Series. For every element in the Series that matches the datetime object passed, that element is appended to an array. The demand is a numpyfloat64.

```py
date_chosen = dt.datetime(2019, 4, 2) 
raw_csv = pd.read_csv(data_series, sep=',', na_values=missing_values)

demand_s = pd.to_numeric(raw_csv['DEMAND'])          # extracts demand
date_series = pd.to_datetime(raw_csv['DATE'])        # extracts date

demand_needed = []                        # which demand values match the date_chosen
day = date_series.dt.day                  # only includes day 
for i in day:
    if day[i] == date_chosen.day:         # if element in day is same as chosen one
        demand_needed.append(demand_s[i]) # append matching element 

print(type(date_chosen.day))              # = int
print(type(day[2]))                       # = numpy.int64
```

This runs fine but the issue is the demand_needed[] is empty. The date_chosen.day is a standard int and elements of day are numpyint64. **How can I compare int and numpyint64?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `for` loop, `i` is the value of each row in the `Series` `"day"`, it's not the index.  So your loop should be structured more like:

```
date_chosen = dt.datetime(2019, 4, 2) 
raw_csv = pd.read_csv(data_series, sep=',', na_values=missing_values)

demand_s = pd.to_numeric(raw_csv['DEMAND'])
date_series = pd.to_datetime(raw_csv['DATE'])

demand_needed = []
day = date_series.dt.day
for idx, d in day.iteritems():
    if d == date_chosen.day:
        demand_needed.append(demand_s.iloc[idx])
```

But a better solution IIUC, would be to use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) rather than iterating:

```
demand_needed = raw_csv.loc[raw_csv.DATE.dt.day.eq(date_chosen.day), 'DEMAND']
```

Or if you need the output as a `list` instead of `Series`, use:

```
demand_needed = raw_csv.loc[raw_csv.DATE.dt.day.eq(date_chosen.day), 'DEMAND'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first solution works perfect.  The second returns AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values but I'm fine with just iterating.

Comment: You’ll just need your `pd .to_datetime(raw_csv[‘DATE’])` line to fix that first